# Swift Firebase: Identify Change in Database

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing a chat application and attempting to implement readReceipts. I have the following Firebase database structure, and when a message is opened, I will do a `updateChildValue`. This will update the Bool to true, like so:

```
Snap (messages) {
    "-L7E-3km6bvx3WWFHeuj" = 1;
    "-L7E-MXzwmZ9iv6Bj0oM" = 1;
    "-L7E-N5pm-FGtb3m3AOr" = 1;
    "-L7E-Q2cRJz9DDFgRWL_" = 1;
    "-L7E-U4r1vd94i-xbNTh" = 1;
    "-L7E1LdrJaqZDjIkWd7X" = 1;
    "-L7EBz3hxfJ-E3f7joJ6" = 1;
    "-L7EE8A5eZNyey12GcHB" = 1;
    "-L7EEwX2m-rrPYFgDoA8" = 0;
    "-L7EFA7CHfyRoECUkeLm" = 0;
    "-L7EFPICxdWQcrLOEUkM" = 0; //Updating this will change Bool to 1
    "-L7EJ1byG2KLKZf_Cspv" = 0;
    "-L7EKRmXYz_94UrIPGhS" = 0;
}
```

I listen for `childChanged` on my `messages` node, and when the update changes to `true`, I will update the views of the `collectionViewCells`. However, implementing `childChanged` will always extract the whole messages node.

Is there a way to identify the exactly which id gets the update and hence obtain the indexPath to update the `collectionViewCells`? Alternatively, is there a better way to implement readReceipts?

Comment: The `childChanged` event fires on the child node that changed under the location where you listen. If that doesn't seem to work for you, post the [minimal, standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another observer function just for your case

from [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseReference)

> [observeEventType:andPreviousSiblingKeyWithBlock:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)observeEventType:andPreviousSiblingKeyWithBlock:) is used to
>   listen for data changes at a particular location. This is the primary
>   way to read data from the Firebase Database. Your block will be
>   triggered for the initial data and again whenever the data changes. In
>   addition, for FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded, FIRDataEventTypeChildMoved,
>   and FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged events, your block will be passed the
>   key of the previous node by priority order.

```
func observe(_ eventType: DataEventType, andPreviousSiblingKeyWith block: @escaping (DataSnapshot, String?) -> Void) -> UInt
```

Example:

```
Database.database().reference().child("messages").observe(.childChanged) { (snapshot, key) in
    print(key)
    //"-L7EFPICxdWQcrLOEUkM"
}
```